# unsual theme / interface

Tags: themes

Hello I’m currently developing a wordpress site for a company i’m working for. The site is basically going to be used for internal purposes and to be used as a manual for new workers. They want something with a interface on the front page to get from 1 page to the next so it flows. I’ve not came across any theme that can seem to do this that suits there needs.

To describe it better, imagine the user is goes onto the website, and begins the training, they link the first link and read that first article, they can then go to to the next section. but if they want they can come out into a hub like layout where they can see the following steps.

I’ve no idea if this exists but if anyone can give any suggestions I would be most grateful.

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Just use Posts and next/prev posts link (see Codex).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use your `index.php` as index page. Add a default loop and style the output to your needs.

Then - in your `single.php` file - just add links to the next/previous post using the template tag: [`get_next_posts_link()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_next_posts_link/) and [`get_previous_posts_link()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_previous_posts_link/).

That's the default way in WordPress to link to other posts/pages.

To make a link back to your index site, just use the `home_url('/');` function.